# Display text written with ckeditor on a website created with .NET Core

Tags: asp.net, database, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, ckeditor

I created a text with the ckeditor editor on the website and I want to store it in the database in the description column and display it on the website, but the text with html tags showing that I want the displayed text to be without tags. Codebacks are created with .NET Core.

Please help me if anyone knows a solution to not displaying the tags.

HTML markup:

```
<table id="myTable" class="table border table-striped table-bordered mt-2 mx-auto w-75 table-custom--4">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" class="hidden">شناسه</th>
            <th class="hidden"></th>
            <th class="hidden"></th>
            <th class="hidden"></th>
            <th scope="col" class="py-3">عنوان</th>
            <th scope="col" class="py-3">نام فایل</th>
            <th scope="col" class="py-1">توضیحات</th>
            <th scope="col" class="py-3">تاریخ بارگذاری</th>
            <th scope="col" class="py-3">دریافت</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
        <tr>
            <td class="hidden">@item.id</td>
            <td class="hidden"></td>
            <td class="hidden"></td>
            <td class="hidden"></td>
            <td>@item.title</td>
            <td dir="ltr"><span class="custom-fontFamily--1">@item.fileName</span></td>
            <td>@item.description</td>
            <td>@item.uploadDate.ToShamsiMyDocuments()</td>
            <td class="py-2"><a href="/ProvinceArea/Management/DownloadMyDocuments/@item.id"><i class="fa fa-download fa-2x text-decoration-none"></i></a></td>
        </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The text that is displayed:

[image]

The format I want to display:

[image]

Comment: Use `@Html.Raw(item.description)`